# Python logger is cleaned up before atexit handler

Tags: python, logging, scope, atexit

I'd like to use Python's [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to show messages at the startup and shutdown of a proxy. The proxy is cleaned up using the [`atexit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html). However, it looks like the logger is cleaned up before the proxy. How can I get expected behaviour? Here is a working example:

```
import atexit
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
LOG = logging.getLogger()
LOG.level = logging.INFO

class Program(object):
    def __init__(self):
        LOG.info("Hello")

    def __del__(self):
        LOG.info("Bye")

p = Program()

def cleanup(proxy):
    del proxy

atexit.register(cleanup, p)
```

And the output from running the script from a shell:

> INFO:root:Hello
>   Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'" in `<bound method Program.__del__ of <__main__.Program object at 0x7f467c9aabd0>>` ignored

With the same behaviour across different versions and operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you [can't rely on `__del__` ever being called](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)<sup>1</sup> -- and by extension, you can't rely on any sort of environment being set at that time.

Might I suggest a context manager?

```
class Program(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._finalized = False
        LOG.info('Hello')
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.__del__()
        self._finalized = True
    def __del__(self)
        if self._finalized:
            return
        LOG.info('Bye')

with Program() as p:
    ...
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note the clause at the end of the paragraph about interpretter shutdown and the red warning box about the "precarious circumstances" around when `__del__` is envoked.</sup>

Comment: My limitation with this strategy is that the proxy `p` is imported elsewhere from this source file, so that `p` needs to be persistent.

Comment: FWIW, I think a better solution would be for the user to import the _class_ and then use it as a context manager.  Of course, `__exit__` could simply call `__del__` if you wanted (I've updated my answer to reflect that pattern).  This more-or-less mimics how file objects' cleanup pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that Python sets module attributes to `None` during interpreter shutdown (in versions prior to 3.4), and you cannot guarantee getting the "Bye" out. You could avoid the error message by defining `__del__` as

```
def __del__(self):
    if LOG:
        LOG.info('Bye')
```